# Change Application icon using pywebview python

Tags: python-3.x, pywebview

I have created a GUI application using pywebview in python and want to change application icon shown in menu bar, By default it is shown as python icon in windows. I am new to this library and want to change default icon to custom icon so is there any way to do this?

Comment: Here's the related issue on GitHub https://github.com/r0x0r/pywebview/issues/185 (I see the OP already commented there)

Comment: Is there any work around for this? at least in windows machine it is not looking good in windows not usable for making enterprise product if we can't remove icon

Answer (score 0):

In the PyWebView framework if you are using the QT web engine as GUI then you have to add a window icon manually in the site packages **"\Python39\Lib\site-packages\webview\platforms\qt.py"** file. Simply paste the code given below into class BrowserView Class Decorator **init**().

```
   class BrowserView(QMainWindow):
      def __init__(self, window):
        from PyQt5 import QtGui
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('icon.ico'))
```